# Ordering of code chunk outputs in Rmd/HTML reports

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

I have a summary figure that I want to insert at the top of my HTML report generated using knitr/rmarkdown. But the inputs of this figure depend on outputs generated from downstream code chunks and child documents. Is there a way to do this without having to put the summary figure at the end of the document?

I have tried ref.label='last' option in the top level code chunk (with eval=FALSE) to add a duplicate code chunk in the end of the document {r last, eval=TRUE}, but has not worked for me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert HTML anywhere into your document referencing the figure by the name `knitr` will use for it.

To figure out the name, temporarily change the YAML header to something like this:

```
  output: 
    html_document:
      self_contained: FALSE
```

This won't embed figures in the output, they'll be kept in a separate directory.  Open the output in an editor, or view source in a browser, and look for the line that displays the figure.  In my test example below, it was being displayed by this code:

```
<p><img src="Untitled2_files/figure-html/rnormplot-1.png" width="672" /></p>
```

I copied that line into the document, and removed the `self_contained` setting, and got this source code:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

This is the figure before it was generated:

<p><img src="Untitled2_files/figure-html/rnormplot-1.png" width="672" /></p>

And here it is being generated:

```{r rnormplot}
x <- rnorm(100)
plot(x)
```
````

One key is to name the code chunk that generates the plot (mine is named `rnormplot`) because that helps to make sure the figure name is independent of the rest of the document.